# Eclipse - An error has occured. See the log file null

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I know this issue was posted like a thousand time. However, non of them seem to solve my issue.

When trying to open Eclipse, whether by clicking the on .exe or thru cmd with -clean command, I receive "*An error has occured. See the log file null.*".

So as mentioned in the other post, I deleted the **.snap file** or the **workbench folder** or the whole **.metadata folder** and yet, the error pops up. So I deleted Eclipse and downlaoded the Eclipse Installer .. and surprise .. same error.

Since I deleted Eclipse I do not have any log I'd know of.

Hope one of you, have a guidance for me, that would be great. :)

Thanks

Comment: Provide some more information that might be unique to your situation, such as Eclipse version, OS, location you've installed to, Java version, have you modified eclipse.ini, etc. The more details you provide, the more likely someone can help identify what's wrong.

Comment: I was using Eclipse Mars 2 32-bit at C:\Program Files\eclpise\ on Windows 7 with Java 1.8.0_91 32-bit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was using Eclipse Mars 2 32-bit at C:\Program Files\eclpise\ on Windows 7 with Java 1.8.0_91 32-bit as well. Don't know why, but I ended up deleting Java and reinstalling it and it worked.

@E-Riz, thanks for you're help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I was facing the same problem probably because I had multiple JVM versions installed in my machine. I fixed the problem by specifying the exact JVM I wanted eclipse to use in the eclipse.ini file.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

In my circumstance, I ask my friend about java version (java -version in windows terminal). All you need is reinstall Java as his recommendation. 
(My java: java 1.8.0_161 Java SE and my Eclipse is Java EE 64 bit)